# Get the value of Span class inside a Select Option

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I know it might seem a duplicate but its not.

Here is what my select looks like:

```
<select id="avpMy4Y7E4cH_-iIRmmAK6-2GsEOu6Sjr-0-0"> 
 <option value="1Ltr [ <span class=money>Rs.1,495.00</span> ]">...</option> 
</select>
```

I want to get the value of the class "money" only.

Here is what I tried:

```
var val = $('#avpMy4Y7E4cH_-iIRmmAK6-2GsEOu6Sjr-0-0 option:selected').find('.money').val();
```

But this return empty value.

How can I get that specific value?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: The `[ <span class...` is just text, it's not HTML and not in the DOM (other than as the value property of the option) - as such, no DOM navigation methods will find it.

Comment: Jquery version of @RyanWilson's answer: `var val = $("<div>").html($("#avpMy4Y7E4cH_-iIRmmAK6-2GsEOu6Sjr-0-0 option:selected").val().match(/\[(.*)\]/)[1]).find(".money").text();`  (except `ltr [` is also not valid HTML, so extract the parts inside `[]`)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit unclear as to what you want returned, but this will return the `textContent` of the span as well as the `classNames`. Span elements don't have value properties.

You can use `DOMParser` to convert the selected option text to an HTML document, select the elements from the document matching that selector, and extract the `textContent`

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    const opt = document
         .querySelector('#avpMy4Y7E4cH_-iIRmmAK6-2GsEOu6Sjr-0-0 option:checked');
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    //convert the value of the selected option to html document
    const htmldoc = parser.parseFromString(opt.value, "text/html");
    //select all elements with className money from html document
    const moneys = htmldoc.querySelectorAll('.money');
    //iterate each and display it's textContent
    moneys.forEach((a) => {
        console.log(a.textContent);
        //if you want to read the classNames
        a.classList.forEach((b) => {
            console.log(b);
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<select id="avpMy4Y7E4cH_-iIRmmAK6-2GsEOu6Sjr-0-0"> 
 <option selected value="1Ltr [ <span class=money>Rs.1,495.00</span> ]"></option> 
</select>
```